# Bold window borders with fixed size

Tags: vb6

From Windows Vista, although some windows are not resizable, but the borders are bold. Is there a way to make bold window borders(unresizable) in VB6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Form's `BorderStyle` property dictates if the window will be resizable or not. You can chose between the following:

```
0 - None (no border)
1 - Fixed Single
2 - Sizable
3 - Fixed Dialog
4 - Fixed ToolWindow
5 - Sizable ToolWindow
```

As far as the visual appearance of the window in Vista, the resizing behavior shouldn't be affected.

### Edit

If you want to prevent the form from resizing while keeping the resizable border style, you can override the `Height` and `Width` in the `Form_Resize` event:

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()
    Me.Width = m_lngOriginalWidth
    Me.Height = m_lngOriginalHeight
End Sub
```

You will need to store the original `Height` and `Width` at some point. You can do this in `Form_Load` or declare constants to store the original values:

```
Dim m_lngOriginalWidth As Long
Dim m_lngOriginalHeight As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
    m_lngOriginalWidth = Me.Width
    m_lngOriginalHeight = Me.Height
End Sub
```

Comment: Sizable(2) makes the border bold, but the form is resizable. 1 and 3 is unresizable but the border is thin. I want a way to make the border bold but unresizable.

Comment: I edited the Answer with code that lets you keep the resizable look while preventing the form from being resized.